# Capturing custom PayPal data using PHP

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have a custom store where I'm selling a single product (as a gift), I need to be able to store the recipients address (different from paypal users), a message for the gift and the name they want their gift to be from (if any).

I'd really like to capture the data on this page:

http://sendvalentinesflowers.co.uk/responsive-buy-rose.html

It appears that the standard buttons don't allow this much data to be passed/stored along side a transaction. I'm just wondering how this HAS to be done with IPN? I'm looking for the simplest way to do it.

Comment: what you should do is store the data  locally before sending them to paypal, then retrieve it from your database when paypal confirms the payment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would save all of the information in your local database as "pending" prior to sending the user over to PayPal for payment.  You can include the invoice parameter in your PayPal code and set the value to the record ID of your local record.

This invoice value will be returned in IPN so you can pull the data back out and process it as necessary, and also update the existing record's payment status according to the current IPN.